# Create new ISO from configured distribution

Tags: linux

I have read that this is possible on Windows using Win32DiskImager.exe but I'm looking for a Linux (Mint) based solution.  I have downloaded the latest distribution and configured it with the software I need and now I'd like to make a *.img file of it - ideally with the ability to not include unallocated sectors as Win32DiskImager.exe apparently does.  Is this possible on Linux?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: "ISO" is much abused term; it really refers to a [CD/DVD specific image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image). There is not much point to such in a Raspberry Pi context.  However, it is often used synonymously with *device image*, since once upon a time the only kind of device image most people ever encountered was an `image.iso` file.  Notice that Pi images use the prefix `.img`.  See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51100/5538

Comment: I have corrected it.  Still need to find how to do it.  I know there are utilities such as mkisofs but the Raspberry Pi has two separate partitions and I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: The headline is still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

To create a complete image of a SD Card on a Linux system you can use the `dd` program. It will copy bit by bit from the SD Card into a file so the file will get the same size than the SD Card. How to do it you can look at
[raspberry pi compute module replication](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93596/79866).

Fortunately you can compress the image to about one sixth of size for example with most used `gzip`:

```
pc ~$ gzip sdcard.img
```

This will make a compressed image `sdcard.img.gz`. You can also use the power of the Unix command line and pipe the commands to one command, for example using the instructions from the linked answer:

```
pc ~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb bs=4M | gzip > sdcard.img.gz
```

To restore it you use:

```
pc ~$ gzip --decompress --stdout sdcard.img.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb bs=4M conv=fsync
```